Prove that $\lim_{x\ \to\infty}\sin\left(x\right)$ doesn't exist ( Only using the epsilon - delta definition of a limit)
Prove that $$\lim_{x\ \to\infty}\sin\left(x\right)$$ doesn't exist
I started off by writing the definition  for a limit not to exist at infinity, namely
$$\exists \varepsilon >0 \forall N >0 | x>N \land |\sin(x)-L|>\varepsilon $$
so I have to find an $\varepsilon$ such that this is satisfied.
so $$\sin(x)> L + \varepsilon$$
$$L -\varepsilon>\sin(x)$$
so this implies $$L -\varepsilon > L + \varepsilon$$
so $\varepsilon=0$, which makes no sense.
What am I doing wrong?

$|y-L|>\epsilon$ does not mean $y >L+\epsilon$ and $y <L-\epsilon$. It means $y >L+\epsilon$ or $y <L-\epsilon$

You were almost there. You have already written that you had to prove:
$$\exists \varepsilon >0 \forall N >0 | x>N \land |\sin(x)-L|>\varepsilon$$
More exactly what is to prove is:
$$\exists \varepsilon >0 \forall N >0 \exists x>N \land |\sin(x)-L|>\varepsilon$$
We know that $sin(x)$ is periodic and that its extrema are $-1$ and $1$. Conceptually, we can guess that even at high values, those extrema will be reached because of the periodicity.
For a formal proof we can just take $\varepsilon = \frac 1 2$, and an arbitrary $N>0$. Take now $x_0 = \lfloor\frac N{2\pi}\rfloor+1$. As $x_0>\frac N{2\pi}$ and $x_0\in\Bbb N$, we have $2x_0\pi+\frac{\pi}2>N$ and $\sin(2x_0\pi+\frac{\pi}2) = 1$. Let us note $x_1=2x_0\pi+\frac{\pi}2$.
We also have $2x_0\pi+\frac{3\pi}2>N$ and $\sin(2x_0\pi+\frac{3\pi}2) = -1$. Let us note $x_2=2x_0\pi+\frac{3\pi}2$
Now whatever $\forall L\in\Bbb R, \left|L-1\right|<\frac 1 2\implies L>\frac 1 2\implies \left|L+1\right|>\frac 1 2$.
In plain English, it means that for $L$ to be a limit, it must verify $\left|L-1\right|<\frac 1 2$ because of the existence of $x_1$. And we have explicitely found $x_2$ verifying $\left|\sin(x_2)-L\right|>\varepsilon$.

There are two sequences, both converging to infinity $x_n=\pi/2+2\pi n$, $n=1,2,3,\dots$ and $x_n'=-\pi/2+2\pi n$, $n=1,2,3,\dots$.
We have (formally) $\sin (x_n)\to 1$ and $\sin (x_n')\to -1$  so $\lim_{x\to\infty} \sin(x)$ cannot exist (as it must be the same for all sequences $x_n\to\infty$).

I should mention, I know nothing of sequences yet. Thanks though. Edited the title to reflect that

how is that possible ? they are generally taught quite early in the curriculum, earlier than continuity with quantifiers for sure...
